# Reference request: maximize the total weight along the path on the graph.

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I am looking for the reference(s) where the following computational problem is discussed:

Given a weighted graph $G$ where each vertex $v_i$ has some weight $w_i$ and a number of "vertices visited" $N$ find a path of $N$ vertices that starts at vertex $v_0$ and has the maximal total weight. Is it NP-hard? I am also interested in the same problem when the graph is arc-weighted and $N$ is the total number of edges visited.

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: Given that the problem of finding all shortest paths from $v_0$ to all other vertices is *not* $NP$ hard, I doubt your problem is...

Comment: Here's an NP-complete problem that sounds a little like yours. Given a graph, a positive integer length for each edge, a opsitive integer $K$, and a pair of specified vertices $s$ and $t$, is there a simple path from $s$ to $t$ of length $K$ or more? This is example ND29 on page 213 of Garey and Johnson.